# Vldm arm instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

```
ptr_arr .req R1   // alias
        .type new332, %object
        .align 2
new332:
        .word 12198,1291, -2198219 ....  //255 numbers
        .size new332,.-new332

        ldr ptr_arr, =#new332 // new332 is a array of integers
        vldm ptr_arr!, {s2 - s8}
```

my doubt is while the vldm instruction is executed and registers s2- s8 are loaded where does the ptr_arr points will it still point to the 1st element of the array?

Comment: The `!` means update the pointer, so no, it will not point to the first element anymore.

Comment: Any idea on where will it point, I think it will point to consecutive element with which the s8 is loaded.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.